# adding files to dictionary and getting value errors

Tags: python

I read and use a big file(smaller chunks don't give me the error) and read it. But when I try to use:

```
kv_pairs = [kv.split(":",1) for kv in tokens[6:]]
features = {k: float(v) for (k, v) in kv_pairs}
```

I get the error:

```
{k: float(v) for (k, v) in kv_pairs}
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I tried to use small chunks of the file and it works there. Problem is with a specific input entry. How do I debug and so that I can remove that line from the file.

Comment: There’s no way to know without seeing your input data. Suggest you wrap a try/except around this and when in an exception, print the values of k and v.

Comment: Can you do with dictionary comprehension syntax ?

Comment: If you found any of the answers useful, consider upvoting...it'll help both you and the answer provider

Comment: Thanks I accepted your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*How do I debug and so that I can remove that line from the file?*"
You don't have to go and delete it in the file. You can just skip it when reading like so

```
kv_pairs = [kv.split(":",1) for kv in tokens[6:] if ":" in kv]
```

This will ensure any member of the `tokens[6:]` that doesn't have a key value pair (separated by ':') will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

That means that there is *at least* one string in `tokens[6:]` that doesn't contain a `:`,
like maybe an empty string, or something else.

**To remove the offending lines, change:**

```
kv_pairs = [kv.split(":",1) for kv in tokens[6:]]
```

**To:**

```
kv_pairs = [kv.split(":",1) for kv in tokens[6:] if ':' in kv] # filter out the strings without a ':'
```